# Breaking an infinite while loop (unresponsive gui)

Tags: python

Solved the problem with Qthread worker class.
https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/
Helped me a lot.

I have a loop for reading and opening datas from directory but when I run the code python is not responding. I can see the files are opening in the terminal but python is not responding. I think it's about infinite loop but I don't know how to break it. (also tried "for loop")

Notes:

1. self.fileindex keeps the order of the selected file in the directory in memory.
2. self.Vfilelist.value keeps the names of files in the directory in memory as a list.
3. self.Vradar.change changes the plot in canvas.
4. start_stream lines are assigned to a button with Qt.

```
    def start_stream(self):
        filelist = self.Vfilelist.value
        f = (len(filelist) - 10)

        while (f < (len(filelist))):

            self.filename = self.Vfilelist.value[f]
            f = f + 1
            print(f)
            time.sleep(1)

            while (self.filename in self.Vfilelist.value):
                
                print("Opening file " + self.filename, file=log.info)
                filename = self.filename
                radar = pyart.io.read(filename)
                # Add the filename for Display
                radar.filename = filename
                self.Vradar.change(radar)
                break

            if f == (len(filelist)):
                f = (len(filelist) - 10)
```

Output:

```
Opening file C:/Users/PC/product_raw\IZM201225092922.KATX8C4

807

Opening file C:/Users/PC/product_raw\IZM201225092943.KATX8C5

808

Opening file C:/Users/PC/product_raw\IZM201225093004.KATX8C6

809

Opening file C:/Users/PC/product_raw\IZM201225093025.KATX8C7

810

Opening file C:/Users/PC/product_raw\IZM201225093048.KATX8C9

811

Opening file C:/Users/PC/product_raw\IZM201225093107.KATX8CA

812

Opening file C:/Users/PC/product_raw\IZM201225093128.KATX8CB

813

Opening file C:/Users/PC/product_raw\IZM201225093149.KATX8CC

814

Opening file C:/Users/PC/product_raw\IZM201225093210.KATX8CD

815

Opening file C:/Users/PC/product_raw\IZM201225093232.KATX8CE

816

Opening file C:/Users/PC/product_raw\IZM201225092922.KATX8C4

807

Opening file C:/Users/PC/product_raw\IZM201225092943.KATX8C5

808

Opening file C:/Users/PC/product_raw\IZM201225093004.KATX8C6

.

.

.
```

Comment: You can print the value of f just after while statement to check if the f is increased as you expected.

Comment: I can see f increase in terminal.

Comment: Instead of using while loop, you should look into “for x in filelist:” this way you wont have to keep track of a index to break out of loop

Comment: tried "for loop" already, didn't work. (edited code with for loop)

Comment: Without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's really hard to understand what's actually going on: for instance, we don't know the values of `self.fileindex` or `self.Vfilelist.value` (and what sets them) or even what calls `start_stream`, which could even cause an undetected recursion, for what we (don't) know. It's also *not* clear the reason of the pyqt5 tag, as there's no possible hint of Qt related objects (but, in case Qt was actually used, using while loops and `time.sleep` would be a serious approach.

Comment: added some notes maybe it'll answer your questions @musicamante

Comment: The part related to the "minimal reproducible example" was a hint: you *should* provide such an example (right now, your code is *not* reproducible). Sorry, but your edit is not enough to clarify the situation.

Comment: After searching for 4 hours, I found out that issue is all about Threading in Qt but couldn't solve the issue yet.

Comment: @malicelik I just realized that there was a typo in my last comment: using while loops and `time.sleep` in Qt would be a serious *mistake*. If the issue is not in your loop, then this whole post becomes invalid (and could be potentially closed), but for future reference always consider providing *valid* MREs and *clear* context (your notes in the edit are not useful and you didn't correctly answer what was asked to you).

Comment: When using complex and long functions, the GUI is running "not responsive" as long as processes continue. There are multiple ways for seperate threads and make responsive gui in qt. But at the moment it seems difficult and not possible to build gui from scratch. I'm open for any easy suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without runnable code, I'm guessing that you really want to do this:

```
def start_stream(self):
    filelist = self.Vfilelist.value
    files_wanted = filelist[-10:]
    
    for filename in files_wanted:
        print("Opening file " + self.filename, file=log.info)
        radar = pyart.io.read(filename)
        # Add the filename for Display
        radar.filename = filename
        self.Vradar.change(radar)
```

It wont necessarily fix any threading issue but it helps make what you are trying to do clearer.

Comment: Edited the code. As you can see in the output the files are opening correctly one by one but python is not responding. I have a Qt GUI which can read radar files and plot them into canvas (this part is working correctly) but if I try to create an loop for reading and plotting last 10 data one by one like an radar animation the gui is not responding.

Comment: After searching for 4 hours, I found out that issue is all about Threading in Qt but couldn't solve the issue yet.

Comment: You are trying to read and plot the last ten values right?
Keep it simple. It is hard without a repro but I've edited my answer using your updated code.

Comment: How can I update the directory for new incoming files in this loop?

Comment: Sorry @malicelik, I don't understand your question. Each time this function is invoked it will operate on the current state of self.Vfilelist and will invoke self.Vradar.change for the files wanted but I don't know what those functions are doing.

Comment: I've solved the problem, forget to mention it here, thank you for attention.